# React watch functionality doesn't work on my Mac

Tags: reactjs, macos, watch

I have tried many different repos and boilerplates but none of them have the watch command working on my Mac, but same code works on other OS and other Mac OS

Last I tried was a very simple code using following commands:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

after this I changed the `src/app.js` file but changes are not reflecting on localhost unless I re-run the `npm start` command

In terminal it shows no errors or any acknowledgement of a change in file.

Terminal state:

```
You can now view my-app in the browser.

  Local:            http://localhost:3000
  On Your Network:  http://192.168.18.6:3000

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.

webpack compiled successfully
```

Specs about my Mac machine:
MacBook: Pro (13-inch, 2018, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports)
MacOs: Monterey v 12.5
Processor: 2.3 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i5

Comment: do you get any console errors when updating files?

Comment: @Sysix nope, no console errors or any achdolwedment in terminal about the update in file as well.